# Lambda support for SLF4J API

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

In Log4j latest API we have Lambda support where I can manage the Debug option easily.

Example:

```
logger.debug("This {} and {} with {} ", 
  () -> this, () -> that, () -> compute());
```

But for slf4j/logback is there any option to have lambda enabled as mentioned above. Please let me know the syntax then.

Comment: SLF4J has already implemented it in their latest version slf4j-api-2.0.0-alpha0 https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#fluent

Comment: The case when simple comment is much more helpful than the top voted answer.

Answer (score 20):

## SLF4J – version 2

Version 2 of [SLF4J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J) has [support](https://slf4j.org/manual.html#fluent) for lambda syntax. This new version also brings a [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).
eg. `logger.atDebug().setMessage("Temperature set to {}. Old value was {}.").addArgument(() -> t16()).addArgument(oldT).log();`

Version 2 is now the current generation of SLF4J. Latest release is 2.0.6 as of 2023-01. Requires [Java 8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8) or later.

Maven POM setting:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [*Download*](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) page. See [this repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api).

Comment: Using 2.0.0-alpha1, doesn't seem like that's the case unforunately

Comment: sadly it's still in alpha

Comment: still at alpha-5 only, what's going on with SLF4J?

Comment: At least in the current alpha there is a method taking `Supplier<String>`, just sadly only on the new fluent API and not on `Logger`

Comment: Slf4j2 is released. Please update this answer.

Comment: @rjdkolb Done. Thanks for the suggestion. FYI, on Stack Overflow you are welcome to make such update modifications yourself to any Question or Answer. Content here is open-source.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, this is not supported yet: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371

Comment: Will come with 2.0.0-alpha1

Comment: I'm trying 2.0.0-alpah1 and the methods still don't take lambdas. Not sure what gives.

Comment: I wonder how much longer we'll have to wait until v2 goes GA.

Comment: So the current version is 2.0.3. Is it supported already?

Answer (score 9):

[slf4j-lambda](https://github.com/kwon37xi/slf4j-lambda) supports that:

```java
import kr.pe.kwonnam.slf4jlambda.LambdaLogger;
import kr.pe.kwonnam.slf4jlambda.LambdaLoggerFactory;

LambdaLogger log = LambdaLoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);

// lambda for message itself
log.debug(() -> createMessage("debug level"));

// lambda for message format's arguments
log.info("info lambda formatter number {}, string {}", () -> 123, () -> "Hello LambdaLogger");

// method reference
public String longRunnigMethod() {
    return "some long running method";
}

log.debug("Long running method logging {}", this::longRunnigMethod);

// exception logging
log.error(() -> "error lambda exception msg - " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
```

Comment: @downvoters Please leave a comment why you dislike this answer. Is it because you don't want to add another library or because this library currently has 7 stars on GitHub only?

Comment: Because we don't want more dependencies in logging libs zoo. There is a request to support lambdas in slf4j(https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371) and there is already such feature in log4j. Please, rather than create another lib, propose a pull request in slf4j.

Comment: @Mr.Cat Please approach the author of the lib and/or take the code and integrate it in slf4j. Double check the license before 

Comment: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371 has been sitting there since 2016. Old discussion here http://slf4j.42922.n3.nabble.com/Lambda-support-in-SLF4J-td4026483.html.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this would work. You'll need to determine if the cost of `new`'ing instances is better than doing it another way.

```java
logger.debug("This {} and {} with {} ",
    defer(() -> this),
    defer(() -> that),
    defer(() -> compute()));
```

Then with this...

```java
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "defer")
public class LogString {
    @NonNull private final StringGenerator generator;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return generator.createString();
    }

    public interface StringGenerator {
        String createString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually defer the execution if the debug level isn't set? I believe the JVM will in fact invoke the defer() method which will invoke the lambda. Maybe you could put a branch in there to check the log level

Comment: Don't take my word for it. Try it out and test it. :)

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher `defer` will be invoked and return a LogString object. The lambda will not be invoked (it's a lambda, not an expression!). Only if the debug level is set and slf4j calls LogString::toString, will the lambda execute.

Comment: Unfortunately this trick creates extra object on stack (`LogString` with factory `LogString.defer()`).

Comment: @gavenkoa Hence the poster's comment about "You'll need to determine if the cost ..." because if `compute()` is expensive, it still may be worth it

Answer (score 4):

**As of August 20th SLF4j version 2.0 was released with support for lambdas.**

Currently only the newly added optional fluent API supports lambdas. They can also be combined with traditional variable parameters. See the following example:

```
logger.atDebug().setMessage("Temperature set to {}. Old value was {}.").addArgument(() -> someSupplier()).addArgument(oldT).log();
```

Reference: [SLF4J Manual - Fluent](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#fluent)